# javafx TabPane show search field in the default dropddown showing hidden tabs

Tags: javafx

How to set search field for the default drop down on the tab pane in JavaFX  ,which shows hidden tab list. and here is my code for tabs on the Tabpane

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250, Color.WHITE);

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setText("Tab" + i);
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Tab" + i));
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tab.setContent(hbox);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

        }

    // bind to take available space
    borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

    borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
    root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```